# Forcing all local files to branch git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I would like to force all my local files to a branch, the branch was checked out from master but, i do not want to merge anything to the master branch i just want to force my code to the specific branch.

The branch i had checked out is called "customerfixes" and it's the same as master right now, but i have made several changes and would like my version of all files on the checked out branch and then, merge to master later on.

How can i force all my local files to a specific branch? "customerfixes" using git ?, also, I have a gitignore file, i still want the gitignore files to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a terminal prompt, assuming you're at the root directory of your project, and are on the correct branch "customerfixes":

```
$ git add -A .
$ git commit -m "Commit message."
$ git push
```

Comment: what does -A mean if you don't mind the question? :). Thank you

Comment: same thing as --all. Here's what git help says about it: "Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching <pathspec> but also where the index already has an entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree. If no <pathspec> is given, the current version of Git defaults to "."; in
other words, update all files in the current directory and its subdirectories. This default will change in a future version of Git, hence the form without <pathspec> should not be used."